# How to view PHP output in a textview in android studio

Tags: php, android, mysql

This is a PHP file i've hosted and the link to it is http://zacseed.com/output.php. i'm developing an android app and i need to view that output (24) in a TextView of the app. I'm new to android, so please give me a very simple way to make it happen.

```html
<?php
$today=date("Y-m-d");
   include("connection.php");
   $mysqli->query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
   $sql="SELECT Temp FROM data where Date LIKE '%" . $today . "%' LIMIT 1";
   $result=$mysqli->query($sql);
   while($e=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
          $output[]=$e; 
     }

   print(json_encode($output)); 
   $mysqli->close();
   
  ?>
```

Comment: Did u try anything in android ?

Comment: I deigned the App. but now  i need to connect it to the database. only to view values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First make web service api like rest or soap which display your data in json fromat and connect with that webservice with android using volley , retorofit or asynctask anything you prefer.

For example, Use this link- https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-json-parsing-retrieve-from-mysql-database/
I am sure this will fulfill your wish. In this link, async task is used to fetch json data but you can use volley or retrofit too.

Comment: Error:(10, 23) error: package org.apache.http does not exist

Comment: this error comes when i use the codes in your link. What should i do?

Comment: That link was for reference, don't just copy them. Please elaborate the error to me.

Comment: `First make web service api like rest or soap`. Nonsense. He has already a .php file. That will do.

Comment: `using volley , retorofit or asynctask `. You cannot compare those three as AsyncTask is a thread and has nothing to do with http. I think you ment using HttpUrlConnection instead.